# Vagrant Default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. (Errno::ECONNABORTED)

[image]

Vagrant Version : 1.9.4
VirtualBox : 5.1.22
Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known issue in vagrant 1.9.4 version and fix will come along version 1.9.5 and here is the comment and fix from vagrant community contributors. (text is copy pasted from [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8520))

Those who want to fix it now in your computer without waiting for 1.9.5 can replace 3 files changed in #8526 in vagrant installation directory.

For example in windows, those files are located in

> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/templates/locales/en.yml
>   C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/errors.rb
>   C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb

replace them with new **en.yml**, **errors.rb** and **communicator.rb**

Then you are good to go. It worked on my Windows 10 machine. One gotcha is in Windows, you have to change folder permission of the directory to edit or create new files.

Patch files:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/8526/files#diff-1d7075fd091c37ce5438eb221ed0b025

Comment: best solution of this problem is now to update your vagrant.