# vagrant 2.2.7 - Can't vagrant up: default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying

Tags: vagrant

This issue has is already described here: [Vagrant Default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886218/vagrant-default-warning-connection-reset-retrying). However, it was supposed to be fixed in vagrant 1.9.5 and I'm using vagrant 2.2.7.

To simplify, I'm just installing vagrant 2.27 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and try to run it with the following Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
end
```

Here is what happens:

```
nicolas@BEL20:~/ansible$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64'
default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/trusty64
==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20190514.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
default: Download redirected to host: cloud-images.ubuntu.com
==> default: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' version '20190514.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ansible_default_1580225223507_34560
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
...
```

So the VM doesn't boot, however, I'm able to ssh to the localhost. Adding the following line to the configuration:

```
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
```

everything works as expected:

```
nicolas@BEL20:~/ansible$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64'
default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/trusty64
==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20190514.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
default: Download redirected to host: cloud-images.ubuntu.com
==> default: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' version '20190514.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ansible_default_1580226061698_99495
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: password
default: 
default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
default: your host and reload your VM.
default: 
default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.40
default: VirtualBox Version: 5.2
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => /home/nicolas/ansible
nicolas@BEL20:~/ansible$
```

But I don't want to authenticate by login/password. What might be going up here ?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `vagrant --version` is 2.2.9, box is `ubuntu/focal64` (can't use password to connect to it).
I also see a forever sequence of:

```
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I had to ensure that `StrictHostKeyChecking` is `no` for `127.0.0.1` (or whatever I see in `vagrant ssh-config`).

Edit: to use `ubuntu/jammy64` I had no other choice but to update vagrant, and was successful with `vagrant --version` 2.2.19

Comment: I'm having the same problem with vagrant --version 2.2.15 and "generic/ubuntu2204"